# Why doesn't class conform to NSCoding?

Tags: swift2, nscoding

I'm getting the following error:

> Type 'TestClass' does not conform to protocol 'NSCoding'

There's only two methods required for NSCoding and both are there.  What am I missing?

```
class TestClass: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var Property1:Double? = 0.00

    required init(code aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        if let priceCoded = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("Property1") as? Double {
            self.Property1 = priceCoded
        }
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder){
        if let priceEncoded = self.Property1 {
            aCoder.encodeObject(priceEncoded, forKey: "Property1")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to clean the project, re-open Xcode and build your project again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed 'r' symbol in an argument name. Update your initializer name to:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

And it will work

Answer (score 0):

I am solving this by using this :-

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

}
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {

}
```

XCode 8.0 (8A218a) , swift 3